# having issue with my php code

Tags: php

displaying variable content is not working

here's my php code with variable name of `$schanName`

```
if($_POST['thisfolder'] == 'default') { 
$schanName = 'Please select a Name';
return; 
}
```

i have tried this to echo out the string where ever i want

```
<div id="err" style="color:#fff;"><?php echo $schanName ?></div>
```

but it doesn't show anything at all.

if i try it like this it will work

```
if($_POST['thisfolder'] == 'default') { 
echo 'Please select a Name';
return; 
}
```

but i don't know what am i doing wrong up there and it's not working.

EDIT #2 HERE my whole page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="error"> i must display that error here</div>

<form class="s_submit" method="post"> 
<label class="def_lab">File:</label> 
<input class="t_box" type='text' name='filename' placeholder='File Name'> 
<label class="t_lab def_lab">Select Folder:</label> 
<select id="soflow" name="thisfolder"> 
<option selected="selected" value="default">Default</option> 
<option value="../embed/tv/xbox/">Xbox</option> 
<option value="Folder2">Folder2</option> 
<option value="Folder3">Folder3</option>
</select><br><br> 
<label class="def_lab">Text Area 1:</label><br> 
<textarea class="tarea_box" type='text' name='strin'></textarea><br><br> 
<label class="def_lab">Text Area 2:</label><br> 
<textarea class="tarea_box" type='text' name='strin2'></textarea><br> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
</form>  

<?php
var_dump($_POST);
$fNum = 'File Name is Required';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
if(empty($_POST['filename'])) {
echo $fNum;
return; 
}
if($_POST['thisfolder'] == 'default') { 
$schanName = 'Please select a Folder';
return; 
}
$filename=$_POST['filename']; 
$words = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"); 
$arrlength = count($words); 
$found = false; 

for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) { 
if($filename == $words[$x]) 
{ 
$found = true; 
} 
} 

if($found) 
{ 
echo 'Not a valid File Name'; 
return; 
} 
// the name of the file to create 
$filename=$_POST['filename']; 
// the name of the file to be in page created 
$strin=$_POST['strin']; 
// the name of the file to be in page created 
$strin2=$_POST['strin2']; 
// the name of the folder to put $filename in 
$thisFolder = $_POST['thisfolder']; 
// make sure #thisFolder of actually a folder 
if (!is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder)) { 
// if not, we need to make a new folder 
mkdir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder); 
} 
// . . . /[folder name]/page[file name].php 
$myFile = __DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder. "/page" .$filename.".php"; 

// This is another way of writing an if statment 
$div = ($strin !== '') ? '<div id="area_code">'.$strin.'</div>' : '<div id="area_code">'.$strin2.'</div>'; 



$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); 
$stringData = ""; 

fwrite($fh, $stringData); 
fclose($fh); 
} 
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't handle the case when the user enters nothing. You only handle when the user enters "default"

Comment: Why are you using 'return' ?

Comment: Is this in a function or something? What's up with the `return`?

Comment: yes but i am talking about this `$schanName` it doesn't show up at all like i did up there it must displays "Please select a Name"

Comment: If you're code is in a function, then the variable `$schanName` won't be defined _outside_ of that function.

Comment: `return` is to not excute the rest of the code i have below of that if statement. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: What _"rest of the code"_? You're if statement ends there either way. I think you need to show us all relevant code. In it's current state, there are too many questions, like: Is that if statement in a function? (still haven't answered that question). Is there more code that you've removed? Is it in the same file as the HTML? The same scope?

Comment: no it's not in a function bro @MagnusEriksson

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` to see what's actually being sent. Likely you'll also need to show us the full HTML form, and you should also enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Well, I've tried asking questions to help us help you but since you don't seem to actually want our help..  I'm out.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you look tired bro :D sorry check my question again i have whole my page

Comment: @Qirel check the bottom of my question bro i have updated it

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you ignoring me bro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need to give this $schanName a value and html form need to be added after php because if u use php after html u can't get values or variable names. But if u use php then html then u can grab values and variables from php into html.

For error report i puted u errors in array so u will get all errors at once.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{ 
    if(empty($_POST['filename']))
    {
       $schanName[] = 'File Name is Required';
    }

    if($_POST['thisfolder'] == 'default') 
    { 
       $schanName[] = 'Please select a Folder'; 
    }

    $filename=$_POST['filename']; 
    $words = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"); 
    $arrlength = count($words); 
    $found = false; 

    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)
    { 
       if($filename == $words[$x]) 
       { 
          $found = true; 
       } 
    } 

    if($found) 
    { 
       $schanName[] = 'Not a valid File Name';
    } 

    // the name of the file to create 
    $filename=$_POST['filename']; 
    // the name of the file to be in page created 
    $strin=$_POST['strin']; 
    // the name of the file to be in page created 
    $strin2=$_POST['strin2']; 
    // the name of the folder to put $filename in 
    $thisFolder = $_POST['thisfolder']; 
    // make sure #thisFolder of actually a folder 
    if (!is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder))
    { 
        // if not, we need to make a new folder 
        mkdir(__DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder); 
    } 
    // . . . /[folder name]/page[file name].php 
    $myFile = __DIR__.'/'.$thisFolder. "/page" .$filename.".php"; 

    // This is another way of writing an if statment 
    $div = ($strin !== '') ? '<div id="area_code">'.$strin.'</div>' : '<div   id="area_code">'.$strin2.'</div>'; 

   $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); 
   $stringData = ""; 

   fwrite($fh, $stringData); 
   fclose($fh); 
} 

?>


<?php
  // display your errors here
  if(!empty($schanName))
  {
     foreach ($schanName as $sn)
     {
        echo '<div id="error"><ul><li>'.$sn.'</li></ul></div>';
     }
  }
?>  


<form class="s_submit" method="post"> 
<label class="def_lab">File:</label> 
<input class="t_box" type='text' name='filename' placeholder='File Name'> 
<label class="t_lab def_lab">Select Folder:</label> 
<select id="soflow" name="thisfolder"> 
    <option selected="selected" value="default">Default</option> 
    <option value="../embed/tv/xbox/">Xbox</option> 
    <option value="Folder2">Folder2</option> 
    <option value="Folder3">Folder3</option>
</select><br><br> 
<label class="def_lab">Text Area 1:</label><br> 
<textarea class="tarea_box" type='text' name='strin'></textarea><br><br> 
<label class="def_lab">Text Area 2:</label><br> 
<textarea class="tarea_box" type='text' name='strin2'></textarea><br> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you expect it to be printed if you define it *after* you're trying to echo it?

Comment: Code edited. U must add a value to variable in this case hes checking is $schanName. And u must check if it's empty if not show value of $schanName .

Comment: check the bottom of my question again bro

Comment: @Mario bro can you tell me what is most securest way to password protect a page ?

Comment: U can do it to give access only to registered/logged in users with session. If user is registered and logged in give him access if not logged in show him a login form.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable $schanName outside the if statement first then you can use it in if statement. It will display in the html also.

This is a scoping issue. Check variable scope for more details.